# Changing utf encoding in visual studio (C++) to UTF-16

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-16

I am making a C++ console program in Visual Studio and I want to use some characters to output to console via `std::cout` or other method that exists in the UTF-16 encoding, such as `ą, ė, ų, ž`, etc.

Is it possible to change the UTF-8 encoding into UTF-16 in Visual Studio, and if so, can you link to any me to any documentation or other sources that explain how to do so?

Comment: The C++ console interface unfortunately doesn't work in UTF-16.  You need special functions to interact with it directly if you want that.

Comment: Visual Studio supports UTF-16 encodings.  There may be some configuration or environmental settings that need to be properly set.  I believe @phuclv has answered several questions in this regard, on SO.  (I use UTF-8 encoding for my VS projects, also with help from phuclv's answers.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the following code, it can achieve your needs

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
  
  wprintf(L"ščžų");
  
}
```

[image]